# Using name-only with other parameters in Git

Tags: git, count, diff

I recently made some changes to a branch that consisted of 90% whitespace changes. Now I'd like to count how many files there were that received the other 10% of the changes. Is there a way to `git diff` while also passing other parameters such as `--ignore-blank-lines`? `git diff --name-only --ignore-blank-lines` returns the entire list of all changed files, not the filtered list. If I omit `--name-only` then the diff shows the exact changes I want but all I want is the *list* of files, I don't care about the changes themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: Were all the whitespace changes related to blank lines? Else, `--ignore-all-space` might be more relevant.

Comment: It was meant more of an example but interchanging `ignore-all-space` still has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, both `--name-only` and `--name-status` use shortcuts: they compare the stored *trees* (name and hash ID) without looking at the *file contents*.<sup>1</sup>

What you'll need to do is use `git diff` (or `git show`) with your whitespace options, then strip out all but the file names.  For instance:

```
$ git show | grep '^diff '
diff --git a/file1 b/file1
diff --git a/file2 b/file2
$ git show --ignore-blank-lines | grep '^diff '
diff --git a/file2 b/file2
```

A bit more massaging (and/or the use of `--no-prefix`) will get you just the file names without the `a/` and `b/` prefixes:

```
$ git show --ignore-blank-lines --no-prefix | grep '^diff '
diff --git file2 file2
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If rename detection is enabled, the detector *does* examine the content of each file.  However, it does not use the whitespace options, so this does not affect the results at all.  The rest of the `--name-status` algorithm continues to just use the stored hash.